# How to set namespace alias with Jaxb2Marshaller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-ws, jakarta-migration

I'm using `org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller` with Spring boot 3 to generated the soap envelope.

At the config, the marshaller is set this way:

```
@Bean
Jaxb2Marshaller marshalle() {
    Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    marshaller.setContextPath("providers.nos.ws.client"); 
    return marshaller;
}
```

According to many posts, the way to customize the namespaces alias is by providing a NamespacePrefixMapper like this:

```
marshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.namespacePrefixMapper", new NamespacePrefixMapper() {
   @Override
   public String getPreferredPrefix(String arg0, String arg1, boolean arg2) {
            return "ns1";
   }
});
```

But this only work for old JAXB that is no longer supported since Java 11, if i'm not mistaken.

The `setProperty` is no longer available. My best guess is adding the following code:

```
var prefixMapper = new NamespacePrefixMapper(){
        @Override
        public String getPreferredPrefix(String arg0, String arg1, boolean arg2) {
            return "ns1";
        }
};
Map<String, ?> map =   new HashMap<>(){
    {
       put("jakarta.xml.bind.namespacePrefixMapper",prefixMapper);
    }
};
      
marshaller.setJaxbContextProperties(map);
```

But it fails with:

```
jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBException: property "jakarta.xml.bind.namespacePrefixMapper" is not supported.
```

I can't find the right bind constant and i'm not even sure if this is the right path.

How can i customize the namespaces alias?

Comment: Instead of renaming the property did you actually have a try with the old property and a new class.

Comment: Yes. Same error.

Comment: Try `org.glassfish.jaxb.namespacePrefixMapper` instead.

Comment: Not supported too.

Comment: Then which JAXB implementation are you using? Spring Boot uses the Glassfish one.

Comment: @MiguelSlv I am also facing similar issue and getting the error `property "org.glassfish.jaxb.namespacePrefixMapper" is not supported`. I have posted the question https://stackoverflow.com/q/78122874/7584240 can you please check and provide suggestion?